# Limit to items visible in AttributeComboBoxes in App SDK 2.0?

Tags: rally

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out why there are missing items from the AttributeComboBox that I am testing. From debugging, I can clearly see that the field config has an array containing all the items, but only 15 are visible in the UI. Is there a config that needs to be specified to increase the number of displayed items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like maxHeight within the listConfig needs to be set. I had tried the maxHeight config, which didn't work, so I had assumed it was not a height issue. For reference, both configs have a default value of 300, so if you're having a similar experience, adjust the height above 300. There is also no extra whitespace if the maxHeight is set well above what may be needed to display all items.

Here is an example:

```
this.example = Ext.widget('rallyattributecombobox', {
    model:'PortfolioItem',
    field:'Something',
    fieldLabel: 'Something',
    labelWidth: 150,
    stateful: false,
    listConfig: {
        maxHeight: 465
    }
});
```